# Can't link GLFW in qtcreator

Tags: opengl, cmake, qt-creator, glfw

I want to link GLFW. I already installed:
sudo apt-get install cmake make g++ libx11-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrandr-dev libxext-dev
Then I create catalog with 2 sub catalogs build(cmake out source build) and libs(for external libraries).
from build catalog I run cmake with command "cmake .."

CMakeLists.txt in main catalog

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(MyProject) # project name

#version number
set(MyProject_Version_Major 1) #numer wersji glowny
set(MyProject_Version_Minor 0) #numer wydania

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)#when not found skip script

# add external subdirectory with another cmake file
add_subdirectory (libs)

include_directories(
libs/glfw-3.0.4/include/GLFW/
)

set(allLibs
${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(Manipulator main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Manipulator ${allLibs})
```

CMakeLists.txt in libs catalog

#### GLFW

```
add_subdirectory (glfw-3.0.4)

include_directories(
glfw-3.0.4/include/GLFW/
)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
set(OPENGL_LIBRARY
${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
)
```

From official documentation I got information:

> add_subdirectory(path/to/glfw) - done, main catalog CMakeList.txt
>
> To be able to include the GLFW header from your code, you need to tell
>   the compiler where to find it.
>
> include_directories(path/to/glfw/include) done, main catalog CMakeList.txt
>
> Once GLFW has been added to the project, the GLFW_LIBRARIES cache
>   variable contains all link-time dependencies of GLFW as it is
>   currently configured. To link against GLFW, link against them and the
>   glfw target.
>
> target_link_libraries(myapp glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}) done, main catalog CMakeList.txt
>
> Note that GLFW_LIBRARIES does not include GLU, as GLFW does not use
>   it. If your application needs GLU, you can add it to the list of
>   dependencies with the OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY cache variable, which is
>   implicitly created when the GLFW CMake files look for OpenGL.
>
> target_link_libraries(myapp glfw ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY} done, main catalog CMakeList.txt
>   ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

Still don't working, got following error:

> error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory  #include

I'm using QTCreator 3.0.1, Ubuntu 14.02 Ubuntu 14.04 lts.

In QTCreator I specified the main CMakeLists.txt directory, build directory (different then source)
Build directory - path to build directory main catalog/build
Working directory - path to main CMakeLists.txt directory
Run configoration: Manipulator

And still don't working. I found working examples on internet but I don't understand them( i.e. they create some directives no idea why).

Comment: This is because you already included `GLFW/` prefix : `include_directories(libs/glfw-3.0.4/include/GLFW/)`. Try to use `include_directories(libs/glfw-3.0.4/include)`.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's works.

Main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6) #minimum CMake version
project(MyProject) #project name


set(MyProject_Version_Major 1) #project version
set(MyProject_Version_Minor 0) 


find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) #find opengl library - stops when not found


add_subdirectory (libs) # add another directory to project(contain glfw library)

#include glfw
include_directories(
libs/glfw-3.0.4/include
)

# create variable to store all libraries
set(allLibs
${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
)


#create Manipulator executable from main.cpp file
add_executable(Manipulator main.cpp)


#links alllibs variable with my executable
target_link_libraries(Manipulator glfw ${allLibs})
```

CMakeLists.txt in libs subdirectory.

```
### GLFW ###

add_subdirectory (glfw-3.0.4)

include_directories(
glfw-3.0.4/include/GLFW/
)
```

tl;dr -

I use this:
    target_link_libraries(Manipulator ${allLibs})
instead of this:
    target_link_libraries(Manipulator glfw ${allLibs})
Forgot glfw variable

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you for your self-answer.