# link GLFW and GLEW to QT-Creator

Tags: qt, glfw, linker-errors

I wanted to learn OpenGl with Cpp using QT-Creator but it seems that i didn't linked my GLFW lib right.

I used

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev libglfw3-doc
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dbg libglew-dev libglew1.13
```

to install them and afterwards, the QT_Creator "showed" me

```
//GLEW
#include "GL/glew.h"
//GLFW
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
```

so I thought, I could use them, but i got an "undifened reference to ...".
I already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536364/cant-link-glfw-in-qtcreator), but it doesn't seem to work. And I never worked with CMake or qmake before, so i can't see my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide my enviroment setup notes for you, or you can read it from my [sites](http://www.dowen.idv.tw/2015/08/26/QT%E4%B8%AD%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9DOpenGL%E6%95%99%E5%AD%B8/), But prevent my site url from invalid someday, I rewrite it here.

### Install glfw

1. First. we need to install dependencies on ubuntu

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
   sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
   ```

### Install glew

1. Then download source package at [official](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)
2. Extract your package and open your terminal, then cd to what your package location which you just extracted.
3. Do following commnad to install

   ```
   make extension
   make 
   sudo make install
   sudo make clean
   ```

### Open QT project and set opengl settings

1. Open a console project in QT
2. Add following settings in your .pro file anywhere.

   ```
   LIBS +=-lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm -pthread
   ```

Try a simple test.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

### Enjoy it

Answer (score 0):

If you have purpose only learn openGL without help library like glfw or glew you can use QOpenglWidget or QOpenglWindow with QOpenglGLFunctions. Qt give wrapper for all openGL functions, however you can use functions from raw opengl. You can not even use QOpenglWindow or QOpengGlWidget. Qt provides a lot of examples, for instance

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same problem. I followed Tokenyet answer but I also added also `-ldl` to the end of `LIBS` in .pro file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, while trying to develop a a console application project using Qt. I fixed the problem using 
-lglfw (not -lglfw3)
it seems like lglfw3 (.so or .a file or whatever) does not exist in the Lib folder unless you compile it your self ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vNLhtXkRYg))

*More over libglm-dev is needed for projects that include glm header files. So lanch ubuntu software center to install it or lanch

```
    sudo apt-get install libglm-dev
```